# PyMongo MongoClient SSH Connection

Tags: python, ssh, pymongo

I'm trying to establish a connection with a MongoDB database via an SSH connection programmatically from python. I can create a MongoClient object to connect locally but I can't see how to establish an SSH connection for my MongoClient to use.

How would I do this?

Comment: You mean via SSH tunneling? The MongoDB network protocol has no builtin support for SSH, but you could use port-forwarding to achieve a connection over an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Yes I do mean via SSH tunneling. How would I go about port-forwarding in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have no local MongoDB running on your machine, then ssh to the server where MongoDB is running:

```
ssh -L 27017:MYHOST:27017 MYUSER@MYHOST
```

Replace MYUSER and MYHOST with your username and host. Then, in another terminal window, run the "mongo" shell from your local computer. By default it connects to localhost:27017, which you've port-forwarded to the remote host. The "mongo" shell should connect correctly.

Then, create a PyMongo connection normally in Python:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> c = MongoClient()
>>> c.test.command('buildinfo')
...
```

More info about SSH tunneling here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

This is not MongoDB-specific at all, any network protocol can be tunneled with SSH port-forwarding.